# ASP.NET MVC 4 application database connection issue after session timeout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, hosting

I have an MVC 4 website using .NET framework 4.5 that works fine at first. It allows me to login and go about my business adding, deleteing and editing records. As such, it is obviously initially connecting to the database without a probelm. However, if I leave it inactive for a while and come back at a later time, and then click a link to a page that shows data from my database, I get the following error:

```
The SSE Provider did not find the database file specified in the connection string. At the configured trust level (below High trust level), the SSE provider cannot automatically create the database file.
```

The website works fine on my localhost, but not when I host it online. I use shared hosting for this. I've done extensive searching online and found lots of people getting the same error, but they don't seem to have a website that works initially and then suddenly stops working. The solutions I've found online say something along the lines of:

```
add these two lines to your web.config file
<remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=p3swhsql-v15.shr.phx3.secureserver.net; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; User ID=****; Password='****';"/>


by default the .net site is trying to find your database in the local filesystem in this case would be the app_data subfolder under the wwwroot directory. simply removing the connectionstring and replacing it with the database connection solves the issue. My example utilizes an SQL db on godaddy's server. however i'm sure you can replace the connection string with the appropriate string for your connection. good luck and i hope this helps anyone that may be having this issue
```

What my program seems to be doing is using the online database when I first login, and then reverting to trying to use the database in the local filesystem once the session timesout. This is very frustrating. My web.config file looks as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="DefaultConnection"/>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=winsqls01.cpt.wa.co.za;Initial Catalog=SportFantasySA;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*****;Password=*****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Please help. I'm desperate to get this working. I understand that it can't create the sql express database in the hosting space, that's why I'm using the connection string for the database on my hosting company's server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have hosted it on Godaddy go for the connection string as

```
<providers>
<remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" />
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
    ..other attributes here... /></providers>

<connectionStrings>
<remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
<add name="LocalSqlServer"
    connectionString="Data Source=xxxx; Initial Catalog=xxx; User ID=xxx; Password=xxx;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: I'm not using GoDaddy, but I've just checked in the control panel for my website and it gives me the option to choose which version of the .NET framework to use. My website uses version 4.5, but the options given here only go up to 4. Could this be the problem, keeping in mind that the website works perfectly for until the session times out?